# How to increase size of blob data type in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

1. How can I upload images of size 3M in my database using blob. My even changed `upload_max_filesize=10M` in php.ini file but it hasn't worked. What should I do?
2. Secondly, is there any way to open an `* .bin` file which is stored in database other than using some external software?

Comment: a `blob` type in mysql is 64k (2^16) bytes. You probably want mediumblob, which is 16meg/2^24. And no, we can't tell you how to open a bin file. "bin" could mean anything.

Comment: i tried even long blob but now it displays "
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39093275 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" and when i click a tab in phpmyadmin it shows "Error in Processing Request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK"......what to do??

Comment: It means you ran out of memory. What are you doing that requires that much?

Comment: i dont know , i even restarted my apache and mysql server but havnt worked ...now i m thinking of reinstalling xampp .. :(
Is there any way other than this??

Comment: it worked after restarting my PC

Comment: Now when i upload an image in localhost it displays the error "INSERT INTO `test_database`.`people` (`id`, `name`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, 'img2', 0xffd8ffe12ec145786966000049492a00080000000c000001040001000000000a00000101040001000000800700000f010200080000009e0000001001020009000000a60000001201030001000000010"

plz correct the error

Comment: Your first question isn't clear; what error are you getting, how are you trying to do the upload? phpMyAdmin has an upload file size limit, but BLOB data will get truncated or the INSERT will fail if the file size is better than the MySQL column -- from what you wrote, it seems you're combining the two problems in to one which makes it hard to fix.

Comment: About your comment, that isn't an error message; that's an SQL query it ran (or attempted to run).